# Convert Map<String, Object> to Map<String, Set<Object>> with filter and streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to convert my map which looks like this:

```
{
  key="someKey1", value=Apple(id="1", color="green"),
  key="someKey2", value=Apple(id="2", color="red"),
  key="someKey3", value=Apple(id="3", color="green"),
  key="someKey4", value=Apple(id="4", color="red"),
}
```

to another map which puts all apples of the same color into the same list:

```
{
  key="red", value=list={apple1, apple3},
  key="green", value=list={apple2, apple4},  
}
```

I tried the following:

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> sortedApples = appleMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.getColour, ???));
```

Am I on the right track? Should I use filters for this task? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you want to proceed with `toMap` you can get the result as follows:

```
map.values()  // get the apples
   .stream() // Stream<Apple>
   .collect(toMap(Apple::getColour, // group by colour
             v ->  new HashSet<>(singleton(v)), // have values as set of apples
          (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;})); // merge colliding apples by colour
```

- stream over the map `values` instead of `entrySet` because we're not concerned with the map keys.
- `Apple::getColour` is the `keyMapper` function used to extract the "thing" we wish to group by, in this case, the `Apple`s colour.
- `v ->  new HashSet<>(singleton(v))` is the `valueMapper` function used for the resulting map values
- `(l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}` is the merge function used to combine two `HashSet`'s when there is a key collision on the `Apple`'s colour.
- finally, the resulting map is a `Map<String, Set<Apple>>`

**but this is better with `groupingBy` and `toSet` as downstream:**

```
map.values().stream().collect(groupingBy(Apple::getColour, toSet()));
```

- stream over the map `values` instead of `entrySet` because we're not concerned with the map keys.
- groups the `Apple`'s by the provided classification function i.e. `Apple::getColour` and then collect the values in a Set hence the `toSet` downstream collector.
- finally, the resulting map is a `Map<String, Set<Apple>>`

*short, readable and the idiomatic approach.*

You could also do it without a stream:

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> res = new HashMap<>();
map.values().forEach(a -> res.computeIfAbsent(a.getColour(), e -> new HashSet<>()).add(a));
```

- iterate over the map `values` instead of `entrySet` because we're not concerned with the map keys.
- if the specified key `a.getColour()` is not already associated with a value, attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function `e -> new HashSet<>()` and enters it into the map. we then add the `Apple` to the resulting set.
- if the specified key `a.getColour()` is already associated with a value `computeIfAbsent` returns the existing value associated with it and then we call `add(a)` on the `HashSet` to enter the `Apple` into the set.
- finally, the resulting map is a `Map<String, Set<Apple>>`

Answer (score 14):

`Collectors.groupingBy` is more suitable than `Collectors.toMap` for this task (though both can be used).

```
Map<String, List<Apple>> sortedApples = 
    appleMap.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Apple::getColour));
```

Or, to group them into `Set`s use:

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> sortedApples = 
    appleMap.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Apple::getColour,
                                           Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),
                                                              Collectors.toSet())));
```

or (as Aomine commented):

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> sortedApples = 
    appleMap.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Apple::getColour, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and `Collectors.toSet()`

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> sortedApples = appleMap.values() // Collection<Apple>
        .stream() // Stream<Apple>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Apple::getColour, // groupBy colour
                Collectors.mapping(a -> a, Collectors.toSet()))); // collect to Set
```

Answer (score 3):

You've asked how to do it with streams, yet here's another way:

```
Map<String, Set<Apple>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
appleMap.values().forEach(apple -> 
    result.computeIfAbsent(apple.getColor(), k -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(apple));
```

This uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), which either returns the set mapped to that color or puts an empty `LinkedHashSet` into the map if there's nothing mapped to that color yet, then adds the apple to the set.

**EDIT:** I'm using `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` to preserve insertion order, but could have used `HashMap` and `HashSet`, respectively.

Comment: nice! +1, it would be better to iterate over the map values though since you're not doing anything with the `key`, i.e. `appleMap.values().forEach(apple -> 
                result.computeIfAbsent(apple.getColour(), k -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(apple));`